# How many 3-letter words without repeating them can be made up of alphabet {a, b, c, d, e, f} in which the letter e or the letter f or both are used?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many 3-letter words without repeating them can be made up of
alphabet {a, b, c, d, e, f} in which the letter e or the letter f or both are used? 
with permutations

Comment: Seems like a straightforward counting problem -- what's your current approach, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I think there are 36 3-letter words with only e and 36 with only f because 3P(4,2)=3*12 and i dont know how to calculate how many words with e and f are there

Comment: Can you repeat letters or not? The wording is unclear.

Comment: No, I cant. I have to give the numbers of 3-letter words with e and without f, the number of 3-letter words with f and without w, and the number of 3-letter words with both (e and f) with the set {a,b,c,d,e,f}

Comment: what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of three lettered words is

6C3(choosing any three letters out of 6)*3!(arranging them)

Number of words where e and f are both NOT used is

4C3*3! (Same logic as above)

The required answer is “Total number of words-number of words not containing e or f”

That is 6C3*3!-4C3*3! = 96

Answer (score 0):

So, you tried to calculate it by seeing how many have only "e" or only "f" and then both. This can get rather complicated so let us take a different approach:

The number of 3-letter words where "e" is the first letter is $5*4$ possibilities. This is identically true for "f" as the first letter. Now, let's count the number of 3-letter words where "e" is the second letter but "f" is not the first letter (so as not to double count): this is $4*4$ possibilities. Identically so for the case where "f" is the second letter but "e" is not the first letter. Finally, let's count the number of 3-letter words where "e" is the third letter but "f" is not the first or second letter(so as not to double count):  this is $4*3$ possibilities. Identically so for the case where "f" is the third letter but "e" is not the first or second letter. So, in total, we have $20*2+16*2*12*2 = 96$ total possible 3-letter words that satisfy the condition.

Alternatively, we can count the number of 3-letter words that don't have either "e" or "f" and subtract that number from the total number of possible 3-letter words creatable using the alphabet: $6*5*4-4*3*2 = 96$ total possible 3-letter words that satisfy the condition.

If you would like me to clarify anything please let me know :)

Comment: Well i try that because i have to give the number of 3-letter words wich contains e but not contain f and vice versa too but i think i understand now :D

Comment: I will do it that way in this comment. You correctly identified how many 3-letter words have only "e" but not "f" and vice versa. So now the words that have both. Well, "e" and "f" can be in three arrangements: 1 2, 1 3, and 2 3 (where "1 2" means letter 1 and letter 2). Now, the third letter can be any one of the four other letters, also the arrangement of "e" and "f" can be "e" then "f" or "f" then "e". So, we have 3 arrangements times 4 choices for the remaining letter times 2 orderings of "e" and "f" giving us $4*3*2 = 24$ words that have both. So, the total amount is $36+36+24 = 96$ words

Comment: Please let me know if you understand or need clarification with a vote or comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Divide given letters $a, b, c, d, e, f$ into two groups $\{a, b, c, d\}$ & $\{e,f\}$

Now, select any two letters out of $\{a, b, c, d\}$ by $^4C_2$ different ways  & any one letter out of $\{e,f\}$ by $^2C_1$ different ways & arrange these three selected letters by $3!$ ways to form 3-letter words having either $e$ or $f$. Therefore, the total number of 3-letter words having either letter $e$ or $f$ $$^4C_2\times ^2 C_1\times 3!=72$$

Similarly, select any one letter out of $\{a, b, c, d\}$ by $^4C_1$ different ways  & two letters out of $\{e,f\}$ by $^2C_2$ different ways & arrange these three selected letters by $3!$ ways to form 3-letter words having both $e$ & $f$. Therefore, the total number of 3-letter words having both letters $e$ and $f$  $$^4C_1\times ^2 C_2\times 3!=24$$

Hence the total number of 3-letter words required
$$72+24=96$$